# Single Sign-on for multiple sites

Tags: asp.net, .net

I just want to get your opinions on the following scenario:
I need to develop multiple web sites that use a single sign-on service. If the user hits the site and he hasn't been authenticated, he needs to be asked for credentials and afterwards should be allowed to use any of the sites for a certain amount of time.
Each user will have a set of roles that can be defined for each of the sites and should be strictly enforced.
Is `OAuth` the best way to go or are there other good options that you know of?
Is it worth the effort to just develop my own service?

I forgot to mention that we do not want to use Google, Facebook, Twitter etc as OAuth providers, so if we go for OAuth we have to make our own provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend OAuth2 or WS-Federation, both are SSO protocols and the effort of implementing both is comparable.

Implementing OAuth2 is possible with the DotNetOpenAuth library, the WS-Federation can be implemented natively in .NET 4.5 as it is a part of the base class library. Note that implementing an identity provider is slightly more difficult that implementing a service provider (an application that just lets users login with the identity provider).

I also recommend a great free ebook, A Guide to Claims Based Security and Access Control:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Read more about machine keys on google. It will give you clear idea about single sign on.

Comment: Although having the same machine keys **is** a way of having sso for multiple sites, this is rather restricted. All sites have to be implemented in .NET. Also, for the forms cookie to be shared, all sites have to be exposed on subdomains of the same domain. True SSO protocols, like OAuth2, Shibboleth or WS-Federation have no such restrictions.